# jquery and DOM element click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a problem with a DOM element that is not recognized by jQuery.

The site is:

http://www.italartsofas.it/collection2012/

I need to add a function to turn the pages when it is clicked.
The function works on the div with class "prima" and "ultima" through this script:

```
$ (". prima"). click (function () {
     $ ('# magazine'). turn ('page', 1);
});

$ (". ultima"). click (function () {
     var pagine = $ ('# magazine'). turn ('pages');
     $ ('# magazine'). turn ('page', page);
});
```

In fact, clicking on "Prima pagina" and "Ultima pagina" script works.

The moment I try to run it on the link "First" with class "jPag-first" pages do not change.

Here's the script:

```
$ (". jPag-first"). click (function () {
     $ ('# magazine'). turn ('page', 1);
});
```

Perhaps because the contents of the div # demo1 is created using jQuery and it is not already existing in the HTML?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: why are giving space between  '.' ,'#' selectors and Ids. There should not be any white space between both.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove space here:

```
$(". prima")
$("# magazine")
```

Should be:

```
$(".prima")
$("#magazine")
```

There should be no space between class/id identifiers.

Comment: My script is correct (no spaces between class and id), I erred when I wrote here.

In addition the script does not work is this:

$ (".jPag-first"). click (function () {
     $('#magazine'). turn ('page', 1);
});